# Numpy position and vector arrays - implement collision detection

Tags: opengl, numpy, collision-detection, vector

I'm using point sprites in PyOpenGL with numpy and glDrawArrays. So I have two arrays, one for the points and one for the vectors.

```
        r = lambda: random.random()        
        self.pts = numpy.zeros((2000,2), dtype=numpy.uint16)
        for pt in self.pts:
            pt[0] = 300*r()
            pt[1] = 200*r()

        self.vectors = numpy.zeros((2000,2), dtype=numpy.uint16)
        for vec in self.vectors:
            vec[0] = 3*r()
            vec[1] = 3*r()
```

Now I need to update the position and vector arrays based on collision with the screen borders. So for example

```
if pt[0][0]-width < 0: pt[0][0] = width; vec[0][0] *= -1
```

In the end I must have a 2000x2 arrays of pts on the screen to feed to opengl.

EDIT - Current solution to keeping points inside a bounding box (0,0,width,height)

```
points [:,0][points[:,0] > width] = width
vectors[:,0][points[:,0] > width] *= -1
points [:,0][points[:,0] < 0] = 0
vectors[:,0][points[:,0] < 0] *= -1
points [:,1][points[:,1] > height] = height
vectors[:,1][points[:,1] > height] *= -1
points [:,1][points[:,1] < 0] = 0
vectors[:,1][points[:,1] < 0] *= -1
```

Comment: You can use up to 5 tags, please use more than one.

Comment: for i, pt in self.pts: if pt[0]-width<0: pt[0]=width; vec[i][0] *= -1 is not the way you want to update a numpy array efficiently. How should I update it? 

(pts < 0) gets me all the pts less than 0, but its a copy not reference so I can't update the original array and I don't have an index to update the second array.

Comment: I notice that I need to change to int16. 

And if you don't know a position is x,y on the screen and the vector is added to it each frame in order to move that position. If you want the object to bounce off the screen borders you must modify the vector based on the position.

Comment: @Mark - By the way, indexing returns a view (essentially a pointer) into the array.  You make your solution more readable by doing something like: `x, y = points[:,0], points[:,1]` and then doing `x[x>width] = width`, etc.  The original `points` array _will_ be updated along with `x`!

Comment: Now I understand exactly whats going on thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question, you want to do something like this:
(Trying to illustrate a few different methods here)

```
import numpy as np

numpoints, numdimensions = 2000, 2

# Generate random points
points = np.random.random((numpoints, numdimensions))
points[:,0] *= 300
points[:,1] *= 200
points = points.astype(np.int16)

# Generate random vectors
vectors = np.random.randint(-3, 3, size=(numpoints, numdimensions)).astype(np.int16)

# Update points and vectors where point x-coords are > width 
points[:,0][points[:,0] > width] = width
vectors[:,0][points[:,0] > width] = -1
```

Comment: This is what I needed thanks, with a bounding box of (0,0) (width,height) I can keep the points inside it by using that syntax.